# Paginación de tabla HTML con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy practicando como paginar una tabla html usando jquery, encontré este código para hacerlo como una libreria jquery. Sin embargo la paginación se realiza poniendole un id al tbody, y lo que quiero es hacerlo usando un id directamente en la tabla.

A continuación dejo el código funcional:

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    
    var listElement = $this;
    var perPage = settings.perPage; 
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');
    
    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }
    
    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }
    
    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;
    }
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
   pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");
    
    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();
    
    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });
    
    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
     
    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
    
    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;
        
        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();
        
        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }
        
        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }
        
        pager.data("curr",page);
       pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");
    
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  

<ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
```

**¿Qué podría hacer para en vez de usar un id en `<tbody>`, usar un id en `<table>` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para podes usar el `selector` de una `tabla`, lo mas fácil sería modificar el valor de la variable `listElement`, por:

```
var listElement = $this.find('tbody');
```

De esta forma, el valor de `$this` puede ser el `table`, y los elementos a paginar los buscara en el `tbody`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    
    var listElement = $this.find('tbody');
    var perPage = settings.perPage; 
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');
    
    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }
    
    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }
    
    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;
    }
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
   pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");
    
    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();
    
    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });
    
    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
     
    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
    
    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;
        
        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();
        
        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }
        
        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }
        
        pager.data("curr",page);
       pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");
    
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
      <th>Table heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
      <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  

<ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
```

Comment: Genial!!!, me sirvió tu respuesta, gracias!

Comment: Muy buena la respuesta pero tengo una duda en el caso de que el número de páginas sea muy grande se muestra todos las indices en la interfaz, cómo se podría delimitar este número. Adjunto imagen
[![Los indices de los paginadores llegan hasta el 106 y se muestra asi, como se puede delimitar ese numero de indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMWMW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMWMW.png)

Comment: Podrías mostrar 5 páginas en lugar de todas. Por ejemplo: suponiendo que estas en la página 8, podrías mostrar `[<<]...[6][7] 8 [9][10]...[>>]`